# Illegal Start of Type alphabet

Tags: java

yes, i have looked at other code, but i have a unique situation, and here it is: okay so my high school teacher is making us do a project to where we have to use IF and ELSE declarations to find out our initials just from YES and NO inputs (0 = no , and 1 = yes) and it has to work with every letter he chooses, but on line 45 it says illegal start of type, but the only thing there is else... anyways here's the code and thank you for the help in advance

```js
/* Objective: practice completing if, if-else,block statements.
 *            and relational operators.
 */
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Alphabet2 { 
  public static void main(String args[]) {
   final int YES = 1;
   final int NO = 0;
   int answer = 0;
   Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in); 
   
    System.out.println("Think of a letter from A to Z\n\n");
    
    System.out.println("0 = A-M");
    System.out.println("1 = N-Z");
    System.out.print("Enter your choice\t");
    answer = kbReader.nextInt();
    if (answer == NO){
     System.out.println("\nOK, A thru M\n");
        System.out.println("0 = A-G");
        System.out.println("1 = H-M");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice\t");
        answer = kbReader.nextInt();
        if (answer == YES){
           System.out.print("\nOK, H thru M \n");
           System.out.print("\n0 = H-J \n");
           System.out.print("\n1 = K-M \n");
           System.out.print("Enter your choice \t");
           answer = kbReader.nextInt();
             if(answer == YES){
               System.out.print("lol");
             }
             
             else {
             }
           }
        //else
          // System.out.print("");
        }
    else {
        System.out.println("OK, A thru G\n");
        }
    }
    else {
     System.out.println("\nOK, N thru Z\n");
        System.out.println("0 = N-S");
        System.out.println("1 = T-Z");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice\t");
        answer = kbReader.nextInt();
        if (answer == NO){
        System.out.println("OK, N thru S\n");
         }
         else { 
            System.out.println("OK, T thru Z\n");
         }      
      }   
   }
```

Comment: Where does that `else` belong?  The `else` that's after another `else`?

Comment: Proper, balanced indentation would make the problem immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom is your code properly indented.

Note that

> ```
>   else {
>     System.out.println("\nOK, N thru Z\n");
> ```

appears after the brace that closes your `main` method.

The reason you get that particular error message is that the parser thinks the `else` that appears after the `main` method is the type for another method or field declaration, because it is not a keyword modifier that could be part of a member declaration.

One way to think about this problem is to break it down completely before filing things in:

```
// A-Z
if (...) {
  // A-M
} else {
  // N-Z
}
```

then one layer more

```
// A-Z
if (...) {
  // A-M
  if (...) {
    // A-F
  } else {
    // G-M
  }
} else {
  // N-Z
  if (...) {
    // N-S
  } else {
    // T-Z
  }
}
```

etc.

---

```
/* Objective: practice completing if, if-else,block statements.
 *            and relational operators.
 */
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Alphabet2 { 
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    final int YES = 1;
    final int NO = 0;
    int answer = 0;
    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);  

    System.out.println("Think of a letter from A to Z\n\n");

    System.out.println("0 = A-M");
    System.out.println("1 = N-Z");
    System.out.print("Enter your choice\t");
    answer = kbReader.nextInt();
    if (answer == NO){
      System.out.println("\nOK, A thru M\n");
      System.out.println("0 = A-G");
      System.out.println("1 = H-M");
      System.out.print("Enter your choice\t");
      answer = kbReader.nextInt();
      if (answer == YES){
        System.out.print("\nOK, H thru M \n");
        System.out.print("\n0 = H-J \n");
        System.out.print("\n1 = K-M \n");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice \t");
        answer = kbReader.nextInt();
        if(answer == YES){
          System.out.print("lol");
        }

        else {
        }
      }
      //else
      // System.out.print("");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("OK, A thru G\n");
    }
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("\nOK, N thru Z\n");
    System.out.println("0 = N-S");
    System.out.println("1 = T-Z");
    System.out.print("Enter your choice\t");
    answer = kbReader.nextInt();
    if (answer == NO){
      System.out.println("OK, N thru S\n");
    }
    else {  
      System.out.println("OK, T thru Z\n");
    }      
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Objective: practice completing if, if-else,block statements.
 *            and relational operators.
 */
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Alphabet2 { 
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    final int YES = 1;
    final int NO = 0;
    int answer = 0;
    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);  

    System.out.println("Think of a letter from A to Z\n\n");

    System.out.println("0 = A-M");
    System.out.println("1 = N-Z");
    System.out.print("Enter your choice\t");
    answer = kbReader.nextInt();
    if (answer == NO){
        System.out.println("\nOK, A thru M\n");
        System.out.println("0 = A-G");
        System.out.println("1 = H-M");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice\t");
        answer = kbReader.nextInt();
        if (answer == YES){
           System.out.print("\nOK, H thru M \n");
           System.out.print("\n0 = H-J \n");
           System.out.print("\n1 = K-M \n");
           System.out.print("Enter your choice \t");
           answer = kbReader.nextInt();
             if(answer == YES){
               System.out.print("lol");
             }

        else{
          System.out.print("");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("OK, A thru G\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("\nOK, N thru Z\n");
        System.out.println("0 = N-S");
        System.out.println("1 = T-Z");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice\t");
        answer = kbReader.nextInt();
        if (answer == NO){
           System.out.println("OK, N thru S\n");
         }
         else { 
            System.out.println("OK, T thru Z\n");
         }      
      }
```

}
}

Comment: Please highlight what you changed in the script and explain why that fixed the problem.